# Quartz scheduler on Windows 7 dev machine and in production on linux machine

Tags: java, linux, quartz-scheduler

I have a Quartz scheduler which is working in my development machine ( Windows 7 ) but unfortunately not in production on my linux machine.

**Code**

```
public class SchedulerClass {
static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SchedulerClass.class.getName());
public SchedulerClass(){

    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Scheduler");
    LOGGER.info("SCHEDULERCLASS:"+rb.getString("groupname"));
    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(TriggerSchedule.class)

            .withIdentity(rb.getString("jobname"), rb.getString("groupname")).build();
    LOGGER.info("JOB "+job);
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity(rb.getString("triggername"),  rb.getString("groupname"))
            .withSchedule(
                    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(rb.getString("cronexp")))
                    .build();
    LOGGER.info("TRIGGER "+trigger);
    try {
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        LOGGER.info("scheduler "+scheduler);
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        LOGGER.info("Scheduler started");

        System.out.println("YYYYY: "+scheduler.getTriggerState(new TriggerKey("DellTrigger")));
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        LOGGER.error("SchedulerException-----"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

it is failing at

```
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
```

the log statements below aren't working and aren't returning any errors.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: No error message, but after this line  "new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();", nothing is executed

Comment: Well you're using a try/catch block. If I read your code correctly your `LOGGER` should contain the message of `e.getMessage()`. Are you debugging into your code and it does not move past the line `Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();`?

Comment: yes, it does not move past the line. As it is deployed in tomcat as war file.i cant debug it,but same is working in my development machine.after deploying, next lines of code are not executing rather it gave error.

Comment: It should jump into the catch block then and you can look at the content of `e.getMessage()` with your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some slf4j jar file conflict in my application.
Actually there are multiple slf4j jar files with different versions,so i removed all of them and and used a single version.Now scheduler started.